# Display randomly from array based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of images that I want to display randomly on my page, however if the image extension matches the url extension, it should skip that certain entry in the array and move onto the next. Here is my code so far.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    //$('.test a').append('<img class="img-responsive portfolio-item thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="">');

    var imgs = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png","img4.png",]

    for ( var n=0; n < 4; n ++){
        var goImg = 'img/' +  imgs[n];
        n = parseInt(n);
        var pItem = 'pItem' +  (n + 1);
        $('#otherProjects').append('<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
            <a href="'+pItem+'.html">
                <img class="img-responsive portfolio-item thumbnail"
                src="'+goImg+'" alt=""> 
            </a>
         </div>');              
    }

});
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: What is the best way to match the url, to an entry in the array IE the url would be projects/pItem1 and the corresponding item in the array would be img1. If these two match, then the array should skip that entry and go onto the next one.

Comment: You hardcoded the url. Are you going to use dynamic url in the future?

Comment: For the time being, I think they will remain static

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {    
    function appendImages(pItem){
        var imgs = ["img1.png","img2.png","img3.png","img4.png",];

        for ( var n=0; n < 4; n ++){
            var goImg = 'img/' +  imgs[n];
            var matchImg = imgs[n].substr(0, imgs[n].lastIndexOf('.'));

            if(pItem != matchImg){
                $('#otherProjects').append('<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">'+
                '<a href="'+pItem+'.html">'+
                    '<img class="img-responsive portfolio-item thumbnail"'+
                    'src="'+goImg+'" alt="">'+ 
                '</a>'+
                '</div>');              
            }
        }
    }   


    var page = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();    //this will return "abc.html"
    appendImages(page.substr(0, page.lastIndexOf('.'))); //this will return "abc"
});
```

If you call the method "appendImages", it will send the current page name (without extension). Inside the method, the url name will be matched against the array values and skip if any matches.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. Let me try to explain better. I have a series of static pages bare/pItem2.html, bare/pItem3.html, etc... That correspond to the images in the array (img1 = pItem1.) I need loop to go through the array and display a random set of images from the array, however the image corresponding to the page we are on should be skipped. So if I was on page pItem1.html it would display img2, img3, img4 The purpose is to display other portfolio items on the buttom of the page, but not the one we are currently on.

Comment: Explain what's your question in detailed.

Comment: How can I use jQuery to read an HTML url (for example bare/pItem1.html) and compare it to a variable inside an array. pItem1 = img1.

Comment: Pop the img that matches, make a random number, and return that index

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Raja, you code helped me get closer to what I was trying to accomplish. Here is what I have so far, and it is working how I need it to, My last step is to have it pick 4 random items from the array rather then the first 4.

```
$(document).ready( function() {



            //array of all portfolio items
            var imgs = ["pItem1","pItem2","pItem3","pItem4","pItem5"]

            //gets the current portfolio page you are on
            var pathname = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop('');
            pathname = pathname.substr(0, pathname.lastIndexOf('.'));


            //checks the imgs array and deletes the current portfolio entry
            var imgs = $.grep(imgs, function(i){
                return(i !== pathname );

            });

            //goes through the array and appends it to the page
            for ( var n=0; n < 4; n ++){

            var imgUrl = 'img/' +  imgs[n] +'.png';

            n = parseInt(n);
            var pItem = imgs[n]

            $('#otherProjects').append('<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="'+pItem+'.html"><img class="img-responsive portfolio-item thumbnail" src="'+imgUrl+'" alt=""></a></div>');

        }

});
```